# i could not able to publish .net core 3.0 version in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Step #0: 6f1169067288: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 6f1169067288: Download complete
Step #0: 6f1169067288: Pull complete
Step #0: f76f782e6432: Pull complete
Step #0: a83b6d8b8290: Pull complete
Step #0: 7bb59f3c128c: Pull complete
Step #0: e7272522e829: Pull complete
Step #0: Digest: sha256:345558080c4215f8d14ccc57b1ddc5d1a3363e3e81fe278c179379ec131563b9
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:345558080c4215f8d14ccc57b1ddc5d1a3363e3e81fe278c179379ec131563b9
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:345558080c4215f8d14ccc57b1ddc5d1a3363e3e81fe278c179379ec131563b9
**Step #0: No valid .NET Core runtime version found for the app or it is not a supported app.
Finished Step #0**
ERROR

### ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:345558080c4215f8d14ccc57b1ddc5d1a3363e3e81fe278c179379ec131563b9" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/d34c890b-4639-44a9-8065-77b4b4a5c158?project=829094548343 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details

**runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex**

Comment: Please update your question with more details like your commands, use case and so on.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue trying to deploy a .NET Core 3.1 app to GCP. but was able to solve it with a couple extra configuration steps.

First, I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/net-core/deploy-an-asp-net-core-app-to-google-cloud-d5ff3ff99b2d) for setting up the deploy from Visual Studio (It specifies that you must use 2017, but the guide is a little out of date and it worked fine with 2019 for me). Make sure to add the app.yaml file to your root directory as it specifies.

Once I reached this point in deploying, I ran into the same error as you. It seems that GCP only supports .NET Core up to 2.1 currently, so I added a DockerFile to my root directory according to [Google's documentation on adding custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/runtime) and configured it to pull Mirosoft's 3.1 image rather than Google's 2.1. I also changed my configuration in my app.yaml from **runtime: aspnetcore** to **runtime: custom**, which specifies that I'm providing my own image for the runtime.

The final app.yaml should look like:

```
runtime: custom

env: flex

# other settings for resources and scaling
...
```

And the final DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "[Your project name].dll"]
```

Comment: This answer from @invigoro should be marked as correct as I successfully deployed to Google App Engine flexible environment with his approach.